# How can I see the number of shutter actuations on a Canon 40D?

Tags: shutter-actuations, canon-40d

How can I find out how many pictures have been taken by a 40D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a PC, you should be able to use [EOSInfo](http://astrojargon.net/EOSInfo.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) which supports retrieving the shutter count on cameras using the Digic III and Digic IV processors (except the 1D range). If you're on a Mac there is [an equivalent tool](http://astrojargon.net/40DShutterCount.aspx)